# Node.js write after send

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have 2 mysql query's 1 for retrieve my groupnumbers and 1 for let show all my doors in that group. Now when i retrieve my groupnumbers i get them in a rray that's why i go map over my array.

But when i use this i get the error cannot write after send someone knows how i can fix this ?

```
  app.post("/door",function (req,res) {
    var door = req.body.door;

    Data(door,function (data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/json' });
        res.write( JSON.stringify(data));
        res.end();
    });

});


function Data(door,next) {
    db.getGroups(function (e,groups) {
        if (e) console.log(e);
        else {
            async.map(groups,function (d) {
                db.getDoorD(d.GroupNumber,door,function (e,data) {
                    next(data);
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your map function will iterate over each element in the array, so the first element closes the response with `res.end()` and when the next one tries to write to the response, it can't.

There's a few options here, but my favorite would be to use the [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library.  That's going to look something like this:

```
app.get("/door",function (req,res) {
db.getGroups(function (e,groups) {
    if(e) console.log(e);
    else
    {
        async.map(groups, db.getDoorD, function (err,results) {
               res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/json' });
               res.write( JSON.stringify(results));
               res.end();
           });
        });
    }
});
});
```

In this case, the `getDoorD` function would issue a callback with the input object or array transformed, and the `results` array will have the final transformation.

You didn't post your SQL here, but there's also a pretty good chance that a better SQL query will make it so you don't have to do the N+1 queries that you have here, and will be more performant besides.

Comment: Thanks but still the same problem

Comment: You didn't follow my code example. Note that the as I mentioned async version of map has a callback in the iterative function.  Each time it's called you have to pass the data to the next, you are calling next on the outer function, which tries to call the same logic each time like you did before.